# Lambda expressions - can not set lambda parameter as argument to method

Tags: java, android, lambda, retrolambda

I'm trying use lambda expressions on Android using **retrolambda**. In code below I need to add listener that is interface:

```
 public interface LoginUserInterface {

        void onLoginSuccess(LoginResponseEntity login);

        void onLoginFail(ServerResponse sr);
    }
```

code

```
 private void makeLoginRequest(LoginRequestEntity loginRequestEntity) {
        new LoginUserService(loginRequestEntity)
                .setListener(
                        login -> loginSuccess(login),
                        sr -> loginFail(sr))
                .execute();
    }

 private void loginSuccess(LoginResponseEntity login) {
         //TODO loginSuccess
    }

 private void loginFail(ServerResponse sr) {
        //TODO loginFail
    }
```

But Android Studio marks red **loginSuccess(*login*)** and **loginFail(*sr*)** as mistakes 
and shows message "*LoginResponseEntity cannot be applied to* " and "*ServerResponse cannot be applied to* "

So I can not set lambda parameter '**login**' as argument to method **loginSuccess(login)**.
Please help me to understand what's wrong with this expression.

Comment: Android compiles with Java 6. No lambdas in Java 6.

Comment: I know, I use retrolambda and other lambda expressions work

Comment: You should mention that in your question.

Comment: If you want to use lambda expressions on android: http://zserge.com/blog/android-lambda.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use lambdas only with [**Functional interfaces**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html). It means that your interface has to specify *only one* method.

To remember about it (simply - to have the ability of using lambdas instead of anonymous classes), the best is to put `@FunctionalInterface` annotation to your interfaces.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface LoginUserInterface {
    LoginResult login(...)
}
```

and then dispatch on the value of `LoginResult`

Comment: You don't need the @FunctionalInterface annotation

Comment: Have I written that you need? I just mentioned that to mark interface as functional and avoid errors in future

Answer (score 2):

Yes, correct answer is "You can use lambdas only with Functional interfaces. It means that your interface has to specify only one method."

For other who will search for some workaround this is my solution:
Devide interface on two functional interfaces

```
public interface SuccessLoginUserInterface {
    void onLoginSuccess(LoginResponseEntity login);
}

public interface FailLoginUserInterface {
    void onLoginFail(ServerResponse sr);
}
```

And your lambda expression will look well:

```
private void makeLoginRequest(LoginRequestEntity loginRequestEntity) {
    new LoginUserService(loginRequestEntity)
            .setsListener(
                    login -> loginSuccess(login),
                    sr -> loginFail(sr))
            .execute();
}
```